# Need help in achieving one requirement

Tags: picklist, lookup, configuration, lookup-filter, developer-org

Business reqmnt: 
Suppose there are 2 managers and 4 employees. Manager1 has Emp1 and Emp2 under him and Manager2 has Emp3 and Emp4 under him.

I want to add a picklist or lookup in Manager's layout that shows only the employees under them not of any other manager's employees. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to use lookup filters but I dont think thats going to work?? Is there any way we can do it apart from coding?

Comment: Are Manager and Employee custom objects, or are you talking about users in a role hierarchy?

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention the objects you're attempting to leverage here, so I'll describe one mechanism using standard functionality.

The User object has a Manager lookup field and the User page layout has a Team related list on it which shows the user & manager details.

This is the out-of-the-box managerial and direct reports functionality. (This operates independently of the role hierarchy.)